# Drupal - User Management - with different levels

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

We are working on a site building using drupal. We have 3 different user profiles / roles.

1. Site Administrator (manage client admin and content)
2. Client Administrator (manage department admins)
3. Department Administrator (manage his own content)

Project Flow:
Site admin, will manage client administrator. Whereas client admin, will manage department administrator.

Since we are at the beginner level in drupal, wanted to know which module will suit the above user management.

Tried adding following modules and permissions, and not able to achieve the desired result

1. Administer Users by Role
2. Profile2
3. Role delegation
4. Role Assign

Please let us know, how to achieve this and the modules to be installed to see the expected result.

Thank in Advance,

Regards

Srinivasan

Comment: I am not able to understand, from reading the question, what exactly you're not able to do.  Out of the box, Drupal lets you set up the roles you call "Site Administrator" (manage more or less everything) and "Department Administrator" (manage his own content).  However, the "Client Administrator" role is not supported out of the box.  I understand that you've considered 4 contributed modules, and have not been able to achieve the desired result.  However,  it is not clear to me what you've found lacking in (say) "Administer Users by Role".  Please expand.

Comment: As u said it is possible to add one more role (Department Administrator) and assign permission to manage content. But i need client admin to be the next level after site administrator. Client admin can add department admin and permissions to manage content. I want to know, how to achieve the "admin->client->department" hierarchy.

Comment: And how did the four modules you list fail to meet your needs?

Comment: i tried the modules listed above. But unable to achieve desired result. Iam able see administrator part (which is alread available by default) - when administrator logs in he can manage the entire people and content. When i added another role / profile - client administrator, i can grant them permissions. But unable to give them the people module and content available to his role alone. Need to know how to achieve this. Also when department administrator logs in, he can manage his client own menu / content alone. (not entire site content).

Comment: Let me know the module /permissions to enable those features. Also i haven't worked in drupal before, so i am not able to get desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try [Organic Groups module](http://drupal.org/project/og)